# Writing Injection vulnerable code sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-injection

I am writing a python file to query which is vulnerable to sql injection.
Here table name and column name on which constraint is made and constraint is given as command line argument while executing python file.
Here is the pyhon file:

```
import sqlite3
import sys

con = sqlite3.connect("univ1.db")
cur = con.cursor()

table = sys.argv[1]
column = sys.argv[2]
constraint = sys.argv[3]
cur.execute( """SELECT * FROM {} WHERE {} = '%s'""".format(table, column)% constraint)
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(','.join([str(val) for val in row]))
```

This code is spposed to be vulnerable to sql injection hence executing following command is expected to drop the specified table from the database along with printing the detail of classroom whose building is blah.

```
python3 query.py classroom building "blah'; DROP TABLE INSTRUCTOR; --'"
```

But since the cursor.execute can execute only one command at a time the program terminates with a warning.
How can I allow executing multiple command. Also note that fetchall function should return the relevant data.
Why am I asking this?
It is a part of an assignment where I am supposed to write both injection disabled as well as injection vulnerable query file.

Comment: Usually we tell people how to write code that is **not** vulnerable to SQL injections. Since many people copy code from here without reading the question I'd even consider answering it dangerous.

Comment: Please answer it. You can delete that after some time

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out python sqlite's is completely invulnerable to drop related attacks.